# VO and DAO, How to design classes and execute query

Tags: java, database, spring, dao

I have a 3 tables:

```
Item: item_id (pk), short_description, ...
SupplierItem: item_id (fk), supplier_id (fk), vendor_product_number, ...
Supplier: item_supplier (pk), name, ...
```

Relation between Item and Supplier is many to many. SupplierItem is 
intermediate table.
I want use VO and DAO.

How to design this in VO (Java)?

After, How can I do the following query in java code.

```
select i.item_id, i.short_description, s.vendor_product_number as FONUA_PRODUCT_CODE 
from item i 
left join supplier_item s
on i.item_id=s.item_id
where ((i.item_id=:item_id) OR :item_id IS NULL)
and i.parent_item_id is null
order by vendor_product_number DESC"
```

I still do not understand the concept in use VO and DAO.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAO would be the java file where you define your query and get the results of the query call on the database.
The results from the query will be saved by setting them as values to the properties of a particular VO.

**For Example:**

Your query returns ,

- item_id, short_description, vendor_product_number

So let us say that you will have to create another java file say ItemVO.java and declare the particular properties of the ItemVO object,
For Ex:

```
private String itemId;
private String shortDescription;
private String vendorShortNum;
/*Define your getters and setters*/
```

In the DAO file you will have to map the query results to the VO file's objects.

```
ItemVO itemVO= new ItemVO();
itemVO.setItemId(/*the particular column value from the query result*/);
itemVO.setShortDescription(/*the particular column value from the query result*/);
itemVO.setVendorShortNum(/*the particular column value from the query result*/);
```

Comment: Do I need to create the intermediate table? (SupplierItem)
How I represent this relationship?

Comment: no you don't have to,even if you decide to fetch a new column with this query you can just add a new property to the VO and set the same from the query Result

Comment: in case you insert something in the table then you will have to use something like hibernate to show the relationship between tables that is for example: table 1 is going to be affected and table 1 has a relationship to table 2 and some columns of table 2 will also get affected in that case you will have to use another mapping technology like hibernate